# Linear Function | Calculus Problem for 1st year of Computer Science-Math (Integrals)

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How do you solve the following:

Having in mind that $f:[0,1]\to\Bbb{R}$ is a continuous function and  $F$ is its primitive ($F(1) = 0$) and that

$$\int_0^1f^2(x)\;\mathrm{d}x\leq3\left(\int_0^1F(x)\;\mathrm{d}x\right)^2$$

**Prove that $f$ is linear.**

It is a new lesson and I did not understand how to approach it. Seeking help or at least a few ideas or starting points to reach the solution that $f$ is linear.

Comment: If $f(x)=cx$ for some constant $c$, $F(x)=cx^2/2$, so $F(1)=0$?

Comment: Hmmm, $f(x)=x^2$ seems to satisfy the inequality.  You get $1/5$ on the left, and $1/3$ on the right.

Comment: The fact that $F$ never enters into the equation makes me think the problem is misstated.

Comment: Edited. The equation had a mistake..

Answer (score 1):

The statement is not true. The following is a counter example.

Let $$f(x)=x^2$$ and $$  F(x)=x^3/3-1/3  $$ We get $$\int_0^1f^2(x)\;\mathrm{d}x =1/5$$ and 
$$3\left(\int_0^1F(x)\;\mathrm{d}x\right)^2 =1/3 >1/5.$$

Comment: If you take x^2 as the f function, the primitive would be x^3 /3. The problem states that F(1) = 0 so x^2 cannot be taken into account as F(1) = 1/3

Comment: That is why I have $F(x)=x^3/3-1/3$

Comment: My bad, but still x^2 is not a linear function, as the problem requires us to prove

Comment: I am not proving the statement. I am providing a counter example to show the statement is false.